# Vaadin Push not working in 10 (flow)

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid, vaadin10

In Vaadin 8, I am able to asynchronously update a `Grid` with incoming websocket data using the `access` method of UI, which locks the thread and performs the updates, then pushes them without the client having to request it.

```
access(() -> addMessage(message));
```

I am trying to use vaadin 10 now, and since the main class you start with doesn't extend UI, I am trying to do it like this:

```
UI.getCurrent().access((Command) () -> addTrade(message))
```

However it is not working, and you have to click somewhere on the page for the update to happen.  I have the `@Push` annotation on the class, so I believe server push should work.. thank you so much guys!

in my servlet:

```
asyncSupported = true
```

have also tried `this.getUI().get().access()`, still not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/3256 that is currently being fixed.

The tickets also suggests a workaround: `grid.getElement().getNode().markAsDirty();`. If the workaround solves the issue, then it's very likely caused by that bug. If not, then there's some other issue that would require further investigation.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much!  I did the `grid.getElement().getNode().markAsDirty();` right before calling refresh (inside the access method)